# nginx not rewriting url for opencart

Tags: nginx, opencart

I have an opencart setup and I'm trying to get nginx to rewrite a url, yet I must be doing something wrong, as nothing I try will work. Here is what I have now that is not working. Just want to remove the index.php?route=common/home from the URL

```
    server {
      ...
        location /index.php?route=common/home {
        rewrite http://www.site.com/ permanent;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your server block closed? your example is missing the closing curly brace.

Comment: Oh, yea, it is yes. Thanks though, had to check to be sure.

Comment: Also rewrite requires two arguments as documented here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
server {
    rewrite ^/index.php?route=common/home$ / permanent;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still not doing it.

Comment: try restarting your nginx server, also you might want to add a simpler redirection rule and see your configs are being read or not.